# Blackberry: Data not fully displayed in BB version 5.0 Operating System/lower such as BB bold3

Tags: blackberry

I developed an application and it works well on OS6 (Operating System 6) but doesn't work well on OS5 (JDK 5.0). The main problem is that I get data via JSON and displays multiple labels on the screen to show the data but the vertical scroll doesn't go allow the user to scroll down beyond a certain point. This makes me wonder if the screen in OS5 have limited contents allowed to be drawn on it. snippet code is shown below

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);

for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); ++i) 
{
    JSONObject moleculevalue = json.getJSONObject(i);//get the json data object

    String tdescription = moleculevalue.getString("Total Description");


   if (tdescription == "") tdescription = "Not Applicable";              

   _fieldManagerMiddle.add(new SeparatorField());
   _fieldManagerMiddle.add(new LabelField("Description: " + tdescription, Field.FIELD_HCENTER));

}
```

Data still exist but users cannot scroll below the screen view.

Can anyone tell me a workaround for this and possibly reasons for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution:
I found out it was a problem with touch devices vs non-touch devices. Hence for non-touch devices, there is a need to set the label control to focusable by

changing

```
_fieldManagerMiddle.add(new LabelField("Description: " + tdescription, Field.FIELD_HCENTER));
```

to

```
_fieldManagerMiddle.add(new LabelField("Description: " + tdescription, Field.FIELD_HCENTER|Field.Focusable));
```

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' (using the green checkmark) so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~